# Use case for appEngine or Kubernetes for GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is this a right use case for deploying  the same in app engine while using memcache service.

1. An Application that can take request for about 10000/min .
2. It take the request , check if it is bot then redirect to failureurl
3. If request is fine then it hit the server to get a charging url and other details from memcache and redirects to a consent page , where we put the charging url on yes button.
4. When the customer hits on yes button then the person will be chaged and thankyou page will be shown

Comment: Either would work, but I'd see if you can get by with App Engine standard setup since it doesn't seem like you need to do a lot of processing per request. Test your processing time locally if possible and if it's over a few seconds per request, consider either more instances or a kubernetes cluster

Answer (score 0):

Judging by what you are mentioning, I would use Kubernetes rather than App Engine for your case, this is due to the "take request for 10000/min" that you mention. App engine cuts the requests that take more than 60 seconds to respond. You can check more about this over at this document: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-handled#specifying_a_request_deadline